# C# Library for easy dynamic reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there any library (like open source projects etc) that makes it easier to use complex reflection like creating objects or classes on the fly, inspecting instances etc?

Thanks

Comment: You mean, other than the types in the System.Reflection namespace?

Comment: Yes, something like a wrapper around them to ease the task of performing the most hard reflection tasks

Comment: Can you describe some of these 'hard reflection tasks' ?

Comment: Create a class on the fly, make an object out of it. Get an existing object and add it a brand new method.

Answer (score 4):

there is a [LinFu](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LinFuPart1.aspx) library available which can do lot other interesting stuffs than reflection... try it

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion I don't think reflection could get any easier to use than it is now. Almost all of the core functionality is wrapped up within the Type class. Just take your time to learn about how it works and you won't need another unnecessary layer on top of it.

Specifically, you can do 'complex things' as creating unitialized objects like this:

```
// Instantiates an uninitialized object of the specified type.
var newObject = (MyObject)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject( elementType );
```

Comment: Well, some caching (of the info obtained by reflection) would be nice. Reflection is pretty slow and retrieving the same `MethodInfo`s or `FieldInfo`s repeatedly is a resource hog. (I know your answer is pretty old...)

Answer (score 1):

There are some interesting [ReflectionHelpers](http://code.google.com/p/rodcommons/wiki/ReflectionHelperExtensions) out there.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection is by definition hard.  It's a level of indirection placed over the whole object structure.  I'm not really sure how you can make it easier, without limiting its power.

Answer (score 1):

If reflection is hard, then it might be possible that you don't have a full understanding of the basics of .Net. You might want to try a tutorial like [this](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/reflection/article.php/c4257).

Answer (score 0):

The MS unit test assembly has PrivateObject and PrivateType which make access to private instance/type members pretty straight forward.

Comment: It is just a wrapper for what you can do through reflection, so it is really nothing special, but I agree that you should not mess with private stuff in instances/types.

Answer (score 0):

[Fastflect](https://github.com/buunguyen/fasterflect) is a rather good library I've used that offers much simpler methods for calling and accessing members, as well as super simple delegate generation for just about anything you may need which increases performance significantly if you cache the delegate. It's documented fairly well which really helps. It's what I used before I wrote my own set of strongly typed generic delegate generation methods.