# How can I create a delegate closure with a reflected type

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I create a closure that uses a reflected type argument? Targeting .net 3.5

Without reflection I would have

```
void Main()
{
    int i = 0;
    Action<Foo> doSomething = (foo) => i += foo.GetNumber();
    var myFoo = new Foo();
    myFoo.UseFoo(doSomething);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

class Foo
{
    public int GetNumber() { return 4; }
    public void UseFoo(Action<Foo> doSomething)
    {
        doSomething(this);
    }
}
```

When `Foo` is a type obtained via reflection from another assembly, how would I set `doSomething`?

```
void Main()
{
    Type fooType = GetType("Foo");
    int i = 0;
    object doSomething = // ???;

    var myFoo = Activator.CreateInstance(fooType);
    fooType.GetMethod("UseFoo").Invoke(myFoo, new object[] { doSomething });
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to give an `Action<Foo>` as argument of `UseFoo()` using reflection?

Comment: Yes, and I want that action to be a closure that can modify `i`

Comment: Good question. I didn't know what a closure was until today. - The compiler generates a class to encapsulate the variable when it detects a closure, so what you're trying to do (or rather the way you're trying to do it) won't work at run time. I wish I had an answer for you, but thanks for the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used both DocXcz and Nikola Anusev's answers to get to this

```
static void Main()
{
    var fooType = typeof(Foo); // get type via any method
    int i = 0;

    Action<object> doSomething = (foo) => i += (int)foo.GetType().GetMethod("GetNumber").Invoke(foo, null);
    var typedDoSomething = (typeof(Program)).GetMethod("DelegateHelper").MakeGenericMethod(fooType).Invoke(null, new object[] { doSomething });

    var myFoo = Activator.CreateInstance(fooType);
    fooType.GetMethod("UseFoo").Invoke(myFoo, new object[] { typedDoSomething });
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

public static Action<T> DelegateHelper<T>(Action<object> generic)
{
    return x => generic(x);
}
```

Basically I needed to use a generic helper method to do the conversion of the `Action<object>` to an `Action<T>` determined at runtime

Comment: Hats off - this is really clever solution! In cases like this, it is common to accept your own answer - I think you can safely do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have statically linked that assembly containing Foo class at compile time, you are true that you cannot use Foo in the code.

You must use reflection also in the closure:

```
Action<object> doSomething = 
(foo) => i+= (int)foo.GetType().GetMethod("GetNumber").Invoke(foo, null);
```

This assumes that Foo's methos UseFoo is something like this and only works with .NET 4.

```
public void UseFoo(Action<Foo> action)
{
    action(this);
}
```

Of course, you should enclose whole calling of UseFoo to try..catch block, because anything in reflection is not guaranteed.

**Update**: This works only in .NET 4, where Action can be passed as Action assumed by the UseFoo method.

Comment: In my case, the assembly containing `Foo` cannot be modified, and cannot be referenced at compile-time. It can only be loaded at run-time.

Comment: Ha I missed that. Now this should help you :)

Comment: Nice, that works for my case. Makes me wonder about if Foo was a struct, but that may be a different question later.

Comment: Since doSomething is of type Action<object>, how is UseFoo() going to accept it as an argument since it's expecting Action<Foo>, not Action<object>?

Comment: @Josh Now, I see that you want this to work in .NET 3.5 - in that case, DocXcz's code wont't work, since it relies on `Action<T>` being contravariant. The contravariance is available starting with .NET 4.0.

Comment: @NikolaAnusev you're right, my quick check was in LINQpad which used .net 4.0. I go an ArgumentException that it cannot convert type with .net 3.5

Answer (score 1):

I am convinced that it is impossible to do *exactly* what you want on .NET 3.5.

Only way that comes *close* does not make use of lambdas, but plain old methods. Essentially, you would have your actions defined in a class similar to the following:

```
public class FooActionMethods<TFoo>
{
    public static void DoSomething(TFoo foo)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int number = (int)typeof(TFoo).GetMethod("GetNumber").Invoke(foo, null);
        Console.WriteLine(i + number);
    }
}
```

Then, you could invoke, for example, `DoSomething` method:

```
Type fooType = // somehow, we get the type from other assembly
object fooInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(fooType);  

Type fooActionType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(fooType);
Type fooActionMethodsType = typeof(FooActionMethods<>).MakeGenericType(fooType);

Delegate action = Delegate.CreateDelegate(fooActionType, fooActionMethodsType, "DoSomething");

fooType.GetMethod("UseFoo").Invoke(fooInstance, new object[] { action });
```

As the whole `FooActionMethod` class is generic, we can make use of reflection (`MakeGenericType`) and create the closed `FooActionMethod` with the exact type of `Foo`. Since we have no information about `TFoo` at compile time, it is only possible to interact with its instances via reflection. To simplify these interactions, check out the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165203/c-sharp-library-for-easy-dynamic-reflection) that dealt with some libraries that would simplify working with reflection.

Other than that, I think there is nothing better you could do. Thanks for the good question - makes for an excellent puzzle! :)

Just as a sidenote, I was also trying to solve this by using expression trees to create lambda expression dynamically. I was not able to find a way to include closures with Expression trees. Otherwise, that method would work fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

A closure, in C#, is something generated by the compiler.  If you wanted the same code generated for you reflected type, you'd have to generate the code manually.

Answer (score 0):

If foo implements a suitable interface you can have the `Action` work on this interface.

If not, you need to either use reflection in your delegate (easier) or compile a delegate at runtime using the expression API (more work, max. performance).

As the C# compiler creates the closure to `i` you need to keep doing that:

```
Action<int> incrementI = inc => i += inc;
```

You can now use increment `i` in your compiled delegate to increment `i`.